# Mansion Build Dimensions

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What are the dimensions for the woodland mansion.[image: woodland mansion] I am trying to find out the dimensions for the woodland mansion build. Doesn't matter which one.

Comment: I'm not crazy right? I swore this was just asked yesterday, what happened to the other one?

Answer (score 1):

The mansion should be 58 blocks wide by 79 blocks long*, with a 2x1x3 entrance.

*This does not include the extension.

Comment: whats the "extension"?

Comment: On some mansions there is relatively small extension that comes out from the main mansion. On others, such as the one in the picture, there is no extension and the third floor covers roughly half of the other to floors.